# How to filter my table with a given input?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I'm trying to let the user choose an year and an metric so my dashboard represents data from this. But seems that my code isn't working how I wanted:

```
dados <- reactive({
  Dados_empresa_2 <- Dados_empresa %>% 
      filter(Ano == input$tempo_1)
      select(Dados_empresa, input$metrica_1, Ano, Mês)
  return(Dados_empresa_2) })

renderDataTable({
  dados() %>%
    var_save <- !!sym(input$metrica_1)
    filter(
      'Media' == mean(dados()$var_save),
      'Mediana' == median(dados()$var_save),
      'Moda' == mode(dados()$var_save),
      'Desvio Padrão' == sd(dados()$var_save),
      'Mínimo' == min(dados()$var_save),
      'Máximo' == max(dados()$var_save)
       ) %>%
  
   datatable(rownames = False) %>%
   formatRound(c('Média', 'Mediana', 'Moda', 'Desvio Padrão', 'Mínimo', 'Máximo'), digits = 2)
})
```

The reactive data (dados) seems to be working as I'm using in another parts of code so I guess the problem resides in the table. What I'm doing wrong ?

If there is a similar question I'm sorry but I really searched about it and couldn't find anything that solved my problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. You create a pipe, but then break it up with a completely separate assignment. This is gibberish to R.
2. You don't use quotes when referencing variables within `dplyr::filter()`, and you don't reference the data frame that `filter()` is being applied to either.

--

```
var_save <- !!sym(input$metrica_1)

dados() %>%    
    filter(
      Media == mean(var_save),
      Mediana == median(var_save),
      Moda == mode(var_save),
      `Desvio Padrão` == sd(var_save),
      Mínimo == min(var_save),
      Máximo == max(var_save)
       )
```

I'm doing this blindly, in order to help further I would need a reproducible example.